# Jquery Backstretch plugin image cuts off at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the backstretch jquery plugin and I'm wondering if there is another way to resize the images to fix the screen. All my images cut off at the top.  I tried using $.backstretch("resize") but no luck. How do you get images to fit? Would this be something I'd have to edit within CSS if backstretch doesn't have another way to resize? Thanks.

Comment: did you try: 'background-position: top;'  so it will cut bottom.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. For some reason, any background attribute I edit doesn't even affect the image. It seems to be controlled by the backstretch script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/issues/19, maybe this will solve the problem:

Set `bgCSS = {left: 0, top: 0}` to `bgCSS = {left: 0, bottom: 0}`, and set centeredX and centeredY to false.

Comment: I'm using the minimized version of backstretch. I'm not sure if I can add that adjustBG function there.

Comment: I set the centeredX and centeredY to false and now it's cutting off the bottom.

Comment: I think the adjustBG function is no longer included with Backstretch, at least in the most recent version it isn't. You can still change those parameters though if you search for them in the file. Anyway, hope cutting off the bottom of the image instead of the top achieves the desired result!